# Devise works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise

I am using devise gem with rails for authentication, my application is running fine locally but the devise views are not accessible when deploying on heroku.

Checking the log gives me following error:

←[app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by   Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML

←[app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML

←[app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

←[heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=clickive.herokuapp.com request_id=739b163c-d2b3-493c-8cfa-ffabc454f468 fwd="148.88.244.110" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 by tes=228

Can anyone help please...

Comment: Can you go to config/production.rb and uncommend/add following line `config.log_level = :debug` and then deploy this to heroku? You should see more detailed error which you can then repost here.

Answer (score 1):

i had similar issue make sure you add to your Gemfile:

`gem 'bcrypt-ruby'`

and then hit `bundle install` and push to heroku once more.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the log and found that i had forgot to run AddUsernametoUsers migration on the production database.